# Reading in .txt and using header string as list name

Tags: python

I have read in a .txt file and have split those lines up into a list. This list contains header info and data. I want to use the header info to name subsequent lists. Because the data contained in the original list (seen below as My_list) are all strings, it is an object which does not support item assignment. I'm trying to make new lists objects with their names defined by the strings in an existing list.

I'd like for Name1 and Name2 to be the names of list objects to which I can append data.

Errors include 'str' object does not support item assignment and 'str' object has no attribute 'append'.

These errors aren't unexpected, but I'm not sure how to turn this string into the name of my new list.

```py
    My_list = [line.split() for line in open("file.txt", "r") ]

    ListNames = My_list[0]

    #My_List[0] = ['Name1','Name2']

    for i in range(1,len(My_list)):
        ListNames[0].append(My_list[i][0])
        ListNames[1].append(My_list[i][1])
```

Comment: Is your file a CSV file? If so use https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: Lists don't exactly have names... Maybe what you need is a dict, where the key is the name and the value is the actual list. Or create a class for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since lists don't exactly have "names" (what you might confuse with reference), maybe you could use dictionaries:

```py
my_list = [line.split() for line in open("file.txt", "r") ]

lists = {name: [] for name in my_List[0]}  # my_List[0] = ['Name1','Name2']

for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
    lists['Name1'].append(my_list[i][0])
    lists['Name2'].append(my_list[i][1])
```

But in general try to avoid reading a whole file to a list (or a string). It is much more efficient to use iterators, where possible. Your case most definetly allows it:

```py
with open("file.txt") as in_f:
    first_line = in_f.readline().strip().split()

    lists = {name: [] for name in first_line}

    for line in in_f:
        line_as_list = line.split()
        lists['Name1'].append(line_as_list[0])
        lists['Name2'].append(line_as_list[1])
```

If by name you mean reference to a list, as in create a variable with that name that points to a list you might use `exec`:

```py
with open("file.txt") as in_f:
    first_line = in_f.readline().strip().split()  # first_line = ['Name1','Name2']

    for name in first_line:
        exec(f"{name} = []")

    for line in in_f:
        line_as_list = line.split()
        Name1.append(line_as_list[0])
        Name2.append(line_as_list[1])
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) about `exec`

Answer (score 0):

if you read the file in as one big string you can do somthing like this

```
lines = []
tempstr = ""

for i in filestring:

    if i == "\n":
        lines.append(tempstr)
        tempstr = ""

    else:
        tempstr+=i
```

this allows your program to detect and ingnore newline charaters

hope this helps

Comment: im kinda new to stack overflow and i will fix it

Comment: This probably works fine now, but merely implements a way to read lines from a file, which fortunatley there are already many built-in ways to do so. Your answer still doesn't address the actual question in hand in any way whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

if you get a list:

```
my_list = ['Name1','Name2']
```

You can create a dict with this list keys and append it:

```
my_list = ['Name1','Name2']
my_dict = {}

for items in my_list:
    #generate keys
    my_dict.setdefault(items,{})
#put new data in key
my_idct["Name1"].update({"Nev_key": "New_value"})
```

So your new list will be something like this:

```
{'Name1': {'Nev_key': 'New_value'}, 'Name2': {}}
```